# Video file not loading properly in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, video, hyperlink

Is there a difference between how a browser loads a Rails application via a url directly typed into a browser vs accessing the same page via a link?

My application's home page (file: streets\show.html.erb --- see below) plays a video (15MB *.MOV) when a user first goes to the site. If, however, the user navigates elsewhere in the application and then returns to the home page by clicking on "Home" link (points to root_path), the page will load but the video will not play (in fact, it's almost like the page can't find the file). If the user refreshes his browser or accesses the page via the browser's url, however, the video will play. Here's the code:

Route.rb file contains:

```
root  'streets#show'
```

venues_controller.rb file contains:

```
class StreetsController < ApplicationController  
  def show
    @street = Street.find(1)
  end
end
```

streets\show.html.erb file contains:

```
<div class="video_pane">
  <%= video_tag(@street.video_link+".MOV", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true) %>
</div>
```

".video_link" above is an attribute in my model that stores the name of the video file. Looking at the source code that Rails produces, the html is passing the correct name and path of the video file:

HTML Source Code:

```
<div class="video_pane">
```

The *.MOV file is 15MB and stored in "public/videos" folder. I'm using Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you got a demo link you could show us?

Comment: Actually, I asked the guys at Heroku about this problem that they recommended that I use Amazon S3 or Cloudfront to store media as putting a file of this size in the assets folder would be super inefficient (i.e. increase slug size, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys at Heroku recommended that I use Amazon S3 or Cloudfront to store media as putting a file of this size in the assets folder would be super inefficient (i.e. increase slug size, etc.)  This solved my problem!